# How to apply check in jsp whether current user is logged in or not

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security

I need a condition in product.tag based on current user is logged in or not? 
Can I put this based on spring header.tag file

```
<div id="userSettings" class="top-nav-bar-layer user-settings header-popup menu-container" style="display:none; right:0;">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="f">
        <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">

        </sec:authorize>
        <li>

        </li>
        <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
            <li>

            </li>
        </sec:authorize>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Supposing you have the user in the session you can use jstl <c:if> tag to check for the user in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this tag:

```
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_CUSTOMERGROUP"></sec:authorize>
```

Comment: Working on a Hybris project?

Comment: I see you posted the same question on Hybris experts :)

Comment: yes I also posted there. Are you also working on hybris?

Comment: Yes I found you there.